# How to invalidate a OAuth2 token (Portal for ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I am developing a REST API with .NET Core 6 using an OAuth 2 authentication. I need a login which does:

- authenticate the user using the REST API
- issue a (user-specific) token I can use in the web application (ArcGIS API for Javascript)

For this, I am using [`AspNet.Security.OAuth.ArcGIS`](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.ArcGIS) and basically the [Server-Enabled Workflow](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/security/arcgis-identity/server-enabled-apps/). Everything works fine until I sign out.

When I sign out, the cookie is removed and I have no access to REST API any more. So far so good **but** the `access_token` is not invalidated. I can still use the token to access ArcGIS web services.

I understand that there is no logout option available with `AspNet.Security.OAuth.ArcGIS`. So I was looking into alternative ways how to invalidate the token:

- [`/oauth/revokeToken`](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/revoke-token.htm): not working with this kind of token

How can I invalidate an `access_token`?

Some of the resources I used:

- [ArcGIS Portal use server-side obtained authorization in the client / JavaScript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256849/arcgis-portal-use-server-side-obtained-authorization-in-the-client-javascript)
- https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/revoking-oauth2-tokens/m-p/492688#M24868
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLr2Ii7iVEs

Comment: Have you posted to the Esri forums? You may grab the attention of a developer over there?

Comment: No I haven't yet. I don't really like using Esri's community forum. Their editor is horrific to use and I usually avoid their forum unless it's really important. However, since I don't get response here, I will consider it. Thanks for reminding me. I went with a workaround and I use a proxy endpoint to funnel all UI requests for the ArcGIS REST API. That way I don't have to expose a token.